# How to change session files location in Odoo?

Tags: session, odoo, odoo-8, erp

I have session files in Odoo saved in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\OpenERP S.A\Odoo\Sessions\` but I want to add another layer of hierarchy such that the sessions are saved in

- `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\OpenERP S.A\Odoo\Sessions\session1\`
- `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\OpenERP S.A\Odoo\Sessions\session2\`
- `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\OpenERP S.A\Odoo\Sessions\session3\`

.
.
.
etc

I checked many links but nothing helped. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the odoo data directory path in configuration file. in windows you can find the config file under `%PROGRAMFILES%\Odoo 8.0-id\server\openerp-server.conf`

in configuration file you can add

```
data_dir = C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\OpenERP S.A\Odoo\Sessions\
```